# Can't access fileserver in other network

Tags: networking, router, dhcp

I have a question: How can i access my Fileserver from my laptop? (see picture) The laptop can ping the Fileserver, but can't connect to it. Also the fileserver does not show itself in 'This computer > Network'.

If i connect the laptop to Router 1 there is no problem.

What would I need to do to let my laptop access the server?

[image: Picture]

Comment: Check out [SMB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) and be sure the router allows the listed UDP and TCP ports to be routed between the subnets. A ping command uses different ports than SMB if you're trying to connect to a shared folder, map a drive, etc. with the "File" server.  **`Directly over TCP, port 445;
Via the NetBIOS API, which in turn can run on several transports:
On UDP ports 137, 138 & TCP ports 137, 139 (NetBIOS over TCP/IP);`** ... I'll be happy to add an answer if you find this helpful, just let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The second router is a Industrial VPN Router (eWON Cosy 131). Can't really forward ports. My guess is that it can't be done

Comment: I've used the Flexy I think and data mailbox and talk2m work wonderfully once you find the gotchas, fine tune, and automate. I'm definitely familiar with that technology. I'd confirm with support if it's possible, it may be with some configuration you're not familiar with. I see the **Plug'n Route (NAT on LAN)** which may be something of relevance if you can configure accordingly.